# Website in Zend framework, not opening in browser

Tags: zend-framework

I have a web site in Zend framework. I am trying to open this site in my browser, passing the path of the file to the address bar. However no content loads and I am faced with a blank page. Any ideas on what could be the problem?

Comment: what path you are using ? also make your error reporting on

Comment: What version of ZF are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your public/index.php

```
/**
 * Display all errors when APPLICATION_ENV is development.
 */
if ($_SERVER['APPLICATION_ENV'] == 'development') {
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
}
```

so you will be able to see what the error is about.

Make sure also that your folders or paths are writeable.